std::queue compile error when use it in a export class
I'm using std:queue in one of my dll export classes to hold a custom type, but now I get compilation errors:
MSVC\14.40.33721\include\deque(874,31): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'std::_Deque_unchecked_iterator<std::_Deque_val<std::_Deque_simple_types<_Ty>>>' to 'unsigned __int64'

I just declared the object and didn't use it anywhere, but when I don't export the class , it compiles through, am I overlooking something?
#define AILU_API __declspec(dllexport)
#include <queue>

template<typename T, size_t size_of_arr>
constexpr uint32_t CountOf(T(&)[size_of_arr]) { return (uint32_t)size_of_arr; }

template<typename T, size_t row, size_t col>
constexpr uint32_t CountOf(T(&)[row][col]) { return (uint32_t)(row * col); }

template<template<typename> typename TT, typename T>
TT<T> operator-(const TT<T> v1, const TT<T> v2)
{
    TT<T> res;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < CountOf(v1.data); i++)
    {
        res.data[i] = v1.data[i] - v2.data[i];
    }
    return res;
}

class AILU_API BC
{
};
class AILU_API SceneMgr
{
public:
private:
    inline static uint16_t s_scene_index = 0u;
    std::queue<BC*> _pending_delete_actors;
};


Can't replicate after removing other errors https://godbolt.org/z/vjoeExsq7. Please post a [mcve] and the complete error message not limiting it with the first text line.

@273K Sorry, the compilation error seems to have originated in some other section, I've modified the example code and this should reproduce the problem

Please explain more about what you are trying to achieve. Specifically what's the purpose of your operator- and it's relation to the std::queue.

The minified code https://godbolt.org/z/hYGc7P3TW

I'm also and confused about this, operator-which is actually part of my math library-accepts a type like Vector3/Vector4, and similarly +/*, which doesn't have an obvious referential relationship to queue. The queue is responsible for storing the object to be deleted from the editor side, which for some reason is delayed.

I don't know 100% what's wrong, but it's a really bad idea to create new operator overloads for standard library types. If you put operator- into a namespace, that fixes the issue: https://godbolt.org/z/Mqn6eEMo7

Yeah I noticed that too, as long as the class that uses queue is not in the same namespace as operator- it compiles fine

Wild guess: your operator- is used when the queue tries to subtract 2 iterators from each other. The queue expects the result of subtraction to be convertible to uint64, but your operator- returns the original iterator type again. Why your operator- would get precedence over the proper one I don't know. Try changing its return type to uint64 and I'd expect you'll see a different error.

Tried it and it compiled successfully, I think I got my answer, thanks guys!
